# unwanted white space between div

Tags: html

This white space between div is driving me crazy, I can not see where the error is, please if you can help me I will thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
    <title>Newsletter</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0!important;
            padding: 0!important
        }

        p {
            margin: 0
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            min-height: 0!important
        }

        td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            white-space: -moz-pre-wrap!important;
            white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap;
            white-space: -pre-wrap;
            white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
            word-wrap: normal;
            word-break: normal;
            white-space: normal
        }

        .main-table,
        .newsletter-row,
        .newsletter-row .inner-row-table {
            width: 600px
        }

        .component.text-component a {
            color: #337ab7;
            text-decoration: none
        }

        .component.text-component a:focus,
        .component.text-component a:hover {
            color: #23527c;
            text-decoration: underline;
            outline: 0
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:640px) {
            body {
                width: auto!important
            }
            .main-table,
            .newsletter-row,
            .newsletter-row .inner-row-table {
                max-width: 600px;
                width: 100%
            }
            .newsletter-row .inner-row-table {
                table-layout: fixed
            }
            .slot {
                width: 100%!important;
                max-width: 100%!important;
                display: block
            }
            .slot.ONE_FOURTH {
                width: 50%!important;
                max-width: 50%!important;
                display: inline-block
            }
            .component .newsletter-button-link .button {
                width: auto!important
            }
            .component .image {
                mso-line-height-rule: exactly
            }
            .component,
            .image table {
                width: 100%!important
            }
            .component .image img {
                max-width: 100%!important
            }
            .slot.ONE_FOURTH .image img {
                max-width: 100%!important
            }
            .component .image img.not-resized {
                width: 100%!important
            }
            .slot-spacing {
                display: none
            }
            .slot .component .newsletter-main-content .image.article-image-container {
                width: 33.3%!important
            }
            #bg_color_table {
                width: 100%
            }
            .non-responsive .slot-spacing {
                display: table-cell
            }
            .non-responsive .slot-spacing.CENTER {
                display: table-cell
            }
            .non-responsive .slot {
                display: table-cell
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.FULL {
                width: auto!important;
                max-width: 100%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.ONE_THIRD {
                width: auto!important;
                max-width: 33.3%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.HALF {
                width: auto!important;
                max-width: 50%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.TWO_THIRDS {
                width: 66.6%!important;
                max-width: 66.6%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.ONE_FOURTH {
                width: auto!important;
                max-width: 25%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.FULL .component .image img {
                max-width: 100%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.ONE_THIRD .component .image img {
                max-width: 100%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.HALF .component .image img {
                max-width: 100%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.TWO_THIRDS .component .image img {
                max-width: 100%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.ONE_FOURTH .component .image img {
                max-width: 100%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.HALF .text_container {
                display: table-cell;
                width: 530px
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:450px) {
            body {
                width: auto!important
            }
            .main-table,
            .newsletter-row,
            .newsletter-row .inner-row-table {
                max-width: 600px;
                width: 100%
            }
            .newsletter-row .inner-row-table {
                table-layout: fixed
            }
            .slot {
                width: 100%!important;
                max-width: 100%!important;
                display: block
            }
            .slot.ONE_FOURTH {
                width: 50%!important;
                max-width: 50%!important;
                display: inline-block
            }
            .component .newsletter-button-link .button {
                width: auto!important
            }
            .component .image {
                mso-line-height-rule: exactly
            }
            .component,
            .image table {
                width: 100%!important
            }
            .component .image img {
                max-width: 100%!important
            }
            .slot.ONE_FOURTH .image img {
                max-width: 100%!important
            }
            .component .image img.not-resized {
                width: 100%!important
            }
            .slot-spacing {
                display: none
            }
            .slot .component .newsletter-main-content .image.article-image-container {
                width: 33.3%!important
            }
            #bg_color_table {
                width: 100%
            }
            .non-responsive .slot-spacing {
                display: table-cell
            }
            .non-responsive .slot-spacing.CENTER {
                display: table-cell
            }
            .non-responsive .slot {
                display: table-cell
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.FULL {
                width: auto!important;
                max-width: 100%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.ONE_THIRD {
                width: auto!important;
                max-width: 33.3%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.HALF {
                width: auto!important;
                max-width: 50%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.TWO_THIRDS {
                width: 66.6%!important;
                max-width: 66.6%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.ONE_FOURTH {
                width: auto!important;
                max-width: 25%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.FULL .component .image img {
                max-width: 100%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.ONE_THIRD .component .image img {
                max-width: 100%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.HALF .component .image img {
                max-width: 100%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.TWO_THIRDS .component .image img {
                max-width: 100%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.ONE_FOURTH .component .image img {
                max-width: 100%!important
            }
            .non-responsive .slot.HALF .text_container {
                display: table-cell;
                width: 530px
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-family: arial, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(0, 240, 240); background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;" background="" border="0">
    <table align="center" class="wrapper-table" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" background="" style="background-color: rgb(0, 240, 240); background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="wrapper-td" valign="top" align="center" background="" style="background-color: rgb(0, 240, 240); background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;">
                    <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="main-table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" class="content">
                                    <table data-structure-type="row" data-row-type="HALF" data-row-id="aefe3328-fced-4167-8a60-0e3046e390e8" data-row-behavior="NORMAL" data-row-repeat-count="5" data-row-sort-products="Orders" data-row-selected-website="3aa4649c98704d1987869ad178988660"
                                        width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="newsletter-row  non-responsive">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="row-td" background="" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;">
                                                    <table width="100%" class="inner-row-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="slot HALF" data-structure-type="slot" data-slot-type="HALF" width="300" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" valign="top" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); max-width: 300px; width: 300px; overflow: visible;">
                                                                    <table class="component text-component" data-component-type="text" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300" style="clear: both; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td style="padding: 10px; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word;">
                                                                                    <div class="text_container newsletter-main-content" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 16px;">
                                                                                        <p style="margin: 0px;"><span style="font-size:16px;"><span style="font-family:Courier,monospace;"><strong>Dear&nbsp;{client_name}</strong></span></span>
                                                                                        </p>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                    <table class="component text-component" data-component-type="text" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300" style="clear: both; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td style="padding: 10px; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word;">
                                                                                    <div class="text_container newsletter-main-content" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 16px;">
                                                                                        <p style="margin: 0px;"><span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;">This is a confirmation that you have booked a&nbsp;<strong>{service_name}</strong></span></span>
                                                                                        </p>

                                                                                        <p style="margin: 0px;">&nbsp;</p>

                                                                                        <p style="margin: 0px;"><span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;">Extras:<strong>{extras}</strong><br />
Total Price:<strong>{total_price}</strong></span></span>
                                                                                        </p>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td class="slot HALF" data-structure-type="slot" data-slot-type="HALF" width="300" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" valign="top" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); max-width: 300px; width: 300px; overflow: visible;">
                                                                    <table class="component text-component" data-component-type="text" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300" style="clear: both; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td style="padding: 10px; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word;">
                                                                                    <div class="text_container newsletter-main-content" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 16px;">
                                                                                        <h2><span style="font-size:16px;"><span style="font-family:Courier,monospace;">Bruz Cleaning Service LLC<br />
Miami, FL &nbsp;</span></span>
                                                                                        </h2>
                                                                                        <h2><span style="font-size:16px;"><span style="font-family:Courier,monospace;">{appointment_date}</span></span>
                                                                                        </h2>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <table data-structure-type="row" data-row-type="HALF" data-row-id="8398b9c1-bf2f-4167-b377-f4f706b915fe" data-row-behavior="NORMAL" data-row-repeat-count="5" data-row-sort-products="Orders" data-row-selected-website="3aa4649c98704d1987869ad178988660"
                                        width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="newsletter-row  non-responsive">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="row-td" background="" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;">
                                                    <table width="100%" class="inner-row-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="slot HALF" data-structure-type="slot" data-slot-type="HALF" width="300" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" valign="top" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); max-width: 300px; width: 300px; overflow: visible;">
                                                                    <table class="component text-component" data-component-type="text" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300" style="clear: both; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td style="padding: 10px; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word;">
                                                                                    <div class="text_container newsletter-main-content" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 16px;">
                                                                                        <h2><span style="font-size:16px;"><span style="font-family:Courier,monospace;">Apointments Details</span></span>
                                                                                        </h2>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                    <table class="component text-component" data-component-type="text" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300" style="clear: both; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td style="padding: 10px; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word;">
                                                                                    <div class="text_container newsletter-main-content" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 16px;">
                                                                                        <p style="margin: 0px;"><span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;">Date:{appointment_date}<br />
Time:</span></span>{appointment_time}</p>

                                                                                        <p style="margin: 0px;"><span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;">Address:</span></span>{client_address}<br />
                                                                                            <span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;">Phone:</span></span>{client_phone}</p>

                                                                                        <p style="margin: 0px;">&nbsp;</p>

                                                                                        <p style="margin: 0px;"><span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;">Payment:</span></span>{payment_type}</p>

                                                                                        <p style="margin: 0px;">&nbsp;</p>

                                                                                        <p style="margin: 0px;"><span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;">Additional Info:</span></span>{custom_fields}</p>

                                                                                        <p style="margin: 0px;">&nbsp;</p>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td class="slot HALF" data-structure-type="slot" data-slot-type="HALF" width="300" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" valign="top" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); max-width: 300px; width: 300px; overflow: visible;">
                                                                    <table class="component text-component" data-component-type="text" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300" style="clear: both; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td style="padding: 10px; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word;">
                                                                                    <div class="text_container newsletter-main-content" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 16px;">
                                                                                        <p style="text-align: justify; margin: 0px;"><span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;">If You Want To Cancel your appointment (fees Apply) Click on the Cancel Button</span></span>
                                                                                        </p>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                    <table data-component-type="button" class="component" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300" align="center" border="0" style="width: 300px; vertical-align: top; background-color: transparent; clear: both;">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <tr class="newsletter-main-content">
                                                                                <td align="center" style="padding: 0px; font-size: 0px;">
                                                                                    <table class="button-wrapper" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="12" style="line-height: normal; white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: baseline; text-align: center; border-collapse: separate; min-width: 10px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); width: auto;">
                                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                                <td width="100%" align="center" style="padding: 12px;"><a class="newsletter-button-link" href="{cancel_appointment_confirm_url}" style="height: 100%; line-height: normal; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-size: 27px; font-weight: normal; width: auto;"
                                                                                                        target="_blank"><span class="button" style="width: 100%; display: block; min-width: 10px;">Cancel</span></a></td>
                                                                                            </tr>
                                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                                    </table>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in classes `.main-table, .newsletter-row, .newsletter-row .inner-row-table`

I'm just added `display: block; & margin-bottom: 12px;` in line 23.

You can see code here :- https://codepen.io/GawiSh/pen/eKbbKQ

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, but you can try these two things:

a) That is because of the white space in `inline-block` elements

***Remove the spacing in your `HTML` code.***

```
<div>one</div><div>two</div><div>three</div>
```

b) **Put a negative margin value in your `CSS`**

```
div{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0px;
  margin-bottom:-5px;
}
```